# How to add <script> to XSLT [Solved with Escaping]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt, accordion

I am using GanntProject, a desktop application for Gantt charts that can export in HTML using some XSL. (I am not 100% familiar with XSL/how this works)

The exported result is available here: http://pixels.studenttribe.org/3DPrinting/3rdYrProjGannt3.6-tasks.html 
(Note the top Hyperlink, "Gannt" which takes you to the chart )

The original XSL for the "Tasks" page is available here:
http://pixels.studenttribe.org/3DPrinting/StackOverflow/
Where the "old" file is the ORIGINAL file that came with the program, and the "gannt-tasks.xsl" is the version I am using (with my edits)
(FileExtension renamed from ".xsl" to ".txt" to allow in-browser viewing)

Question:
Why is it that I get an error if I try to add some Javascript to this XSL file? Is there a solution to have this script included in the HTML automatically upon export?
(You can see the script I manually entered by viewing page source of the first link provided above, the script is right at the top) N.B. the script enables HTML as opposed to displaying plain-text.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jerome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your XSLT is well formed.  Any unescaped `<` or `&` in the JavaScript code will break the XML.

You can "escape" your script by wrapping its content in `<![CDATA[...]]>` like so:

```
<script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
  // Put your script here
]]></script>
```

XML is not as forgiving as HTML.  It has stricter (and simpler) parsing rules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I now have the Javascript automatically added to the HTML using this, and have also learned what "escaping" actually is.

Shall I start a new Stackoverflow question to ask about including accordion layouts to this table?

Comment: I'm glad it solved the issue. Yes, you should definitely split your question in separate parts. Questions and answers on Stackoverflow should be as generally useful to others as possible. Your situation with all the different aspects is very specific. So, maybe edit the question and title and only leave 1) there, create other questions for the other aspects if necessary.  2) Does not have to do anything with XSLT.